# Requesting solution for an error with python3.7 based aux module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running a python code using python3.7 in Ubuntu 18.10.
The code requires use of aux module of python.
So, I installed the aux python module.
After that if I run the code it shows the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from aux.ptb_aux import *
  File "/home/rstudio/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aux/__init__.py", line 40
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone please tell me what might be the source of error and the possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install the aux library

Comment: You are trying to use a horribly outdated module - that syntax (comma instead of `as` to specify the exception variable) has been deprecated since Python 2.6 I believe, disallowed since 3.x.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used "python3.7 -m pip install aux" command to install aux module and it worked fine. Then should I use "as" instead of comma?

Comment: If the module is that old, it's likely to have numerous other 3.x incompatibilities.  It might be a better use of your time to try to find a supported module that does the same thing, rather than trying to fix them all.